# How to replace a single tag with multiple values in PHP?

Tags: php

I am sending a job openings email to my website users. I have the following sentences.

```
Dear user, 
The following jobs are recently posted in our website.
[JOBLIST]
Thank you.
```

If there is only one job, I can use `str_replace("PHP Developer", "[JOBLIST]", $message)`

But I have list of job openings say,

- PHP Developer
- Data Scientist
- Data Entry

I would like to replace the above tag [JOBLIST] with the above job openings probably with a `href` link to the job details.

Comment: Instead of "PHP Developer" just put the HTML code you want.

Comment: Yes, I did it! I created a for-loop to iterate through all the job openings and built a HTML string as explained by @Dum below and I was successful. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$jobs = array("PHP Developer", "Data Scientist", "Data Entry");
$links = array("phpdev","datasci","dataentry");

$str = "";
$n = count($jobs);
$temp = '<li><a href="https://example.com/jobs/{{link}}">{{job}}</a></li>';
$paras = array("{{link}}","{{job}}");

for($i=0;$i < $n; $i++){
   $str .= str_replace($paras,array($links[$i],$jobs[$i]),$temp);
}

$str = "<ul>".$str."</ul>";

$output = str_replace($str, "[JOBLIST]", $message);
```